# Atomic variable vs Normal variable with locks in C++

Tags: multithreading, c++11, stdatomic

Recently I gave an interview to a tech company and the interviewer asked me to tell **which of the operation is faster among a normal increment operation on atomic variable and increment operation on a normal variable with locks.** (This came as a sub question of an original question which goes out of context)

As I don't know what's going under the hood, I gave the reason as one hardware instruction for one increment instead of three and I claimed atomic to be faster.

Now after the interview, while I though of extracting the solution, I found this happening.

Code I've written to test:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <chrono>
#include <thread>
#include <mutex>
#include <atomic>
#include <cmath>
using namespace std;

int iters = 1;

class Timer{
private:
    std::chrono::time_point<std::chrono::high_resolution_clock> startTime,stopTime;
    string method_name;
    // stop function
    void stop(){
        stopTime = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
        auto start = std::chrono::time_point_cast<std::chrono::microseconds>(startTime).time_since_epoch().count();
        auto stop = std::chrono::time_point_cast<std::chrono::microseconds>(stopTime).time_since_epoch().count();
        auto duration = stop-start;
        cout<<"Time taken : "<<duration<<" μs"<<endl;
    }
public:
    // constructor
    Timer(){
        startTime = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
    }
    // destructor
    ~Timer(){
        stop();
    }
};

std::mutex Lock;
long n_variable = 0;
std::atomic<long> a_variable(0);

void updateAtomicVariable(){
    for(int i = 0 ; i < iters ; i++){
        a_variable++;
    }
}

void updateNormalVariableWithLocks(){
    for(int i = 0 ; i < iters ; i++){
        Lock.lock();
        n_variable++;
        Lock.unlock();
    }
}

int main(){

    int no_th = 1;
    std::thread atomic_threads[10];
    std::thread normal_threads[10];

    // updating once
    cout<<"Updating atomic variable once"<<endl;
    {
        Timer timer;
        for(int i = 0 ; i < no_th ; i++){
            atomic_threads[i] = std::thread(updateAtomicVariable);
        }

        for(int i = 0 ; i < no_th ; i++){
            atomic_threads[i].join();
        }
    }
    cout<<"Updating normal variable once with locks"<<endl;
    {
        Timer timer;
        for(int i = 0 ; i < no_th ; i++){
            normal_threads[i] = std::thread(updateNormalVariableWithLocks);
        }

        for(int i = 0 ; i < no_th ; i++){
            normal_threads[i].join();
        }
    }

    no_th = 10;
    iters = 1e7;
    //updating multiple times
    cout<<"Updating atomic variable 1e8 times with 10 threads"<<endl;
    {
        Timer timer;
        for(int i = 0 ; i < no_th ; i++){
            atomic_threads[i] = std::thread(updateAtomicVariable);
        }

        for(int i = 0 ; i < no_th ; i++){
            atomic_threads[i].join();
        }
    }
    cout<<"Updating normal variable 1e8 times with 10 threads and with locks"<<endl;
    {
        Timer timer;
        for(int i = 0 ; i < no_th ; i++){
            normal_threads[i] = std::thread(updateNormalVariableWithLocks);
        }

        for(int i = 0 ; i < no_th ; i++){
            normal_threads[i].join();
        }
    }
}
```

Interestingly I got the output as :

```
Updating atomic variable once
Time taken : 747 μs
Updating normal variable once with locks
Time taken : 255 μs
Updating atomic variable 1e8 times with 10 threads
Time taken : 1806461 μs
Updating normal variable 1e8 times with 10 threads and with locks
Time taken : 12974378 μs
```

**Although the numbers are varying each and every time, the relative magnitude remained same.**

This is showing that for one increment operation atomic increment is slower and on the other hand while incrementing the same for multiple times it is showing atomic increment is much faster which is the contrary to first recorded observation of one increment.

I ran this on multiple machines and multiple times and found the same.

Could some one help me to understand what's going on here.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Hint: you "did" 1e7 times "more work" (per thread), but it didn't take nearly 1e7 times as long, in either case.

Comment: Yeah, I observed that too. That could also be counted with proper answer and I'm looking for the same

Comment: A single operation would be too fast to measure; the clock just doesn't have that kind of resolution. Your timing for it is likely dominated by noise in the clock itself. You do have to measure over multiple repetitions.

Comment: Also note: In _some_ programming language libraries (I don't know about C++ specifically) there can be a relatively high "setup" cost that your program pays the first time (or first few times) that it uses any given mutex or atomic object. But what what @IgorTandetnik, said probably is more relevant: It's hard to get _accurate_ measurements of such small time intervals.

Comment: 747 microseconds is *way* too high a cost, totally implausible and certainly an artifact of bad benchmark methodology (failure to do warm up runs so there are page faults, and possible lazy dynamic linking overhead in the timed region).  Or, or that you're actually including thread-startup overhead, which is *vastly* more expensive than a single increment.